# react native ios 0.69.1 React-Codegen Build failed

Tags: react-native

I recently created a new project using `npx react-native init myapp --template react-native-template-typescript`, everything is working in android, but when I try to build for iOS, the build fails due to `React-Codegen` errors specifically in `FBReactNativeSpec.h` file. Below is the build error output from xcode:

[image]

Whole log:

```
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
/Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:2206:46: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0
  d[@"window"] = window.has_value() ? window.value().buildUnsafeRawValue() : nil;
                                             ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:19:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety/RCTTypeSafety/RCTConvertHelpers.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/optional:953:27: note: 'value' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    constexpr value_type& value() &
                          ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
/Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:2208:46: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0
  d[@"screen"] = screen.has_value() ? screen.value().buildUnsafeRawValue() : nil;
                                             ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:19:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety/RCTTypeSafety/RCTConvertHelpers.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/optional:953:27: note: 'value' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    constexpr value_type& value() &
                          ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
/Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:2210:88: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0
  d[@"windowPhysicalPixels"] = windowPhysicalPixels.has_value() ? windowPhysicalPixels.value().buildUnsafeRawValue() : nil;
                                                                                       ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:19:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety/RCTTypeSafety/RCTConvertHelpers.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/optional:953:27: note: 'value' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    constexpr value_type& value() &
                          ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
/Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:2212:88: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0
  d[@"screenPhysicalPixels"] = screenPhysicalPixels.has_value() ? screenPhysicalPixels.value().buildUnsafeRawValue() : nil;
                                                                                       ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:19:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety/RCTTypeSafety/RCTConvertHelpers.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/optional:953:27: note: 'value' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    constexpr value_type& value() &
                          ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
/Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:2223:96: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0
  d[@"isIPhoneX_deprecated"] = isIPhoneX_deprecated.has_value() ? @((BOOL)isIPhoneX_deprecated.value()) : nil;
                                                                                               ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:19:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety/RCTTypeSafety/RCTConvertHelpers.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/optional:953:27: note: 'value' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    constexpr value_type& value() &
                          ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
/Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:2462:68: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0
  d[@"prerelease"] = prerelease.has_value() ? @((double)prerelease.value()) : nil;
                                                                   ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:19:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety/RCTTypeSafety/RCTConvertHelpers.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/optional:953:27: note: 'value' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    constexpr value_type& value() &
                          ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
/Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:2588:110: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0
  d[@"DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR"] = DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR.has_value() ? @((double)DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR.value()) : nil;
                                                                                                             ^
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm:14:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:19:
In file included from /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety/RCTTypeSafety/RCTConvertHelpers.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/optional:953:27: note: 'value' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    constexpr value_type& value() &
                          ^
7 errors generated.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/macbookair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/justChat-gvlyyuoxvfahekfvnoiuaatjtplq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.o /Users/macbookair/Desktop/justChat/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

What I tried so far:

1. delete `podfile.lock`, `cd ios && pod install`
2. `clean build` and then `yarn ios`
3. commented `!use_flipper()` from `Podfile` then `clean build`.

My config:

macOS Catalina
version 10.15.7
XCode 12.4

As mentioned in the image, it is related to `React-Codegen` and it is in newer version of `react-native-0.69.1`, so can anyone help me fix this issue in ios?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET so it should be fixed as mentioned in this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34106

> In iOS Folder go to Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/project.pbxproj

> Change all the 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0' to 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 12.4'. save and run.

Comment: I just found out that if I created project with version 0.69 then i had the problem. There is no problem with version 0.64.2

Comment: If this is not resolved your problem, please check this post: stackoverflow.com/a/75901128/7802590